# Simple Search with fields and provided IDs in ElasticSearch

Tags: json, lucene, elasticsearch

I just want to search my users in ElasticSearch matching multi fields and there document IDs. Currently I have this code to match multi fields only and is working good

```
{ 
"query" : 
    { 
         "multi_match": {
             "fields": [
                "user",
                "email"
             ],
             "query": "John",
             "operator": "and",
             "type": "phrase_prefix"
         }
    }
}
```

but now only small help is needed that how can I make sure that this only searches for those whose Document IDs are ["5","4"]?

I tried this

```
{ 
"query" : 
    { 
         "multi_match": {
             "fields": [
                "user",
                "email"
             ],
             "query": "John",
             "operator": "and",
             "type": "phrase_prefix"
         },
         "filter" : {
          "ids" : {
              "values" : ["5","4"]
             }
         }
    }
}
```

but this is not working. Is it wrong? I give each document my own unique id while storing them. My result from query without filter is something like this

```
"hits": [
        {
            "_index": "MyIndex",
            "_type": "users",
            "_id": "4",
            "_score": 0.70710677,
            "_source": {
                "user": "John Ibraheem",
                "email": "johnibrhaeem@yahoo.com"
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "MyIndex",
            "_type": "users",
            "_id": "9",
            "_score": 0.70710677,
            "_source": {
                "user": "Johnathan",
                "email": "johnathan@yahoo.com"
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "MyIndex",
            "_type": "users",
            "_id": "5",
            "_score": 0.30685282,
            "_source": {
                "user": "Johnsons",
                "email": "johnsons@gmail.com"
            }
        }
    ]
```

I just only want to get John* whose _id is ["5","4"] not "9".

Comment: use explain query of elastic search , that will tell you exactly what wrong. http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html
It takes an id and query in body and will tell you exactly whats going on. Will be very helpful.

Comment: @sahildhankhar it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
{
 "query": 
 {
  "filtered": 
  {
     "query": 
     {
         "multi_match": 
         {
            "fields": ["user","email"],
            "query": "i",
            "operator": "and",
            "type": "phrase_prefix"
         },
         "filter" : {
          "ids" : {
              "values" : ["5","9"]
             }
         }
      }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Abdul Jabbar WebBestow, your query worked and is shorter as I said to Roopendra

Answer (score 1):

Please try below query. In combination of filter.

```
{
  "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
         "multi_match": {
            "query": "John",
            "fields": ["user","email"]
         }
         },
         "filter": {
             "bool": {
                 "must": [
                    {
                        "terms": {
                           "ids": [
                              "5",
                              "4"
                           ]
                        }
                    }
                 ]
             }
         }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: isn't there some shorter way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by shorter way? Is my query is long or anything else?

Comment: Your query is not retrieving any result :( .If I remove filter then it works but not with filter as you said

Comment: @CodeDevil  : I am hoping `ids` available elasticsearch index. try to change `ids` to `_id`.

Comment: Thanks Roopendra for your kind support but @Abdul Jabbar WebBestow query just worked the way I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

there is a query for ids.  this restricts to the given ids.  pass them as the array you put in your example

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-ids-query.html

Comment: I already tried that but may be I am doing it wrong. Please take a look at my edited code if there is something wrong there.

Comment: ES1.0 : ``curl -XPOST localhost:9200/stock/stock/_search -d '{"query": { "match_all": {} }, "filter": { "ids": { "values": [ "US0079031078", "CA0679011084" ] } } }'
{"took":5,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":2,"max_score":1.0,"hits":[{"_index":"stock","_type":"stock","_id":"US0079031078","_score":1.0, "_source" : {"id":"US0079031078","name":"Advanced Micro Dev.","price":null}},{"_index":"stock","_type":"stock","_id":"CA0679011084","_score":1.0, "_source" : {"id":"CA0679011084","name":"Barrick Gold","price":null}}]}}``

Comment: but gives this long error  "error": "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[aiva9T0VRVS7K6ZZ6iY9OQ][oxcave][0]: SearchParseException[[oxcave][0]: query[(email:\"john\" | user:\"john\")],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source